# How to add using HashMap multiple values(different types, an int and a string) with the same key?

Tags: java

I have to store a key with multiple values but my values should be a string and an int. For this problem I have to use List,Stack, Queue or Map, I think that Map is the right choice.

I have a lot of pairs of shoes, and every shoe has a size, a colour and a price. The pairs of shoes must be ordered by their size.

I tought that the key could be the size of the shoes and values should be the colour and the price but I don't know how to implement this.

For example I have:

pair 1, size 36, colour black, price 30$
pair 2, size 36, colour white, price 35$
pair 3, size 37, colour black, price 40$
pair 4, size 38, colour black, price 45$

How could I store all of this using Map(I think) without creating a new class of shoes for example?

Update: I am also allowed to use SortedMap, SortedList, etc.  In the second part of the problem I have to add and remove shoes of a specific size.

Comment: *without creating a new class of shoes* : why don't you want to create a class? That would be the best way

Comment: I'm not allowed, this is the text of the problem :(

Comment: I think your problem gives you pretty strong hints that you have to create a class

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I must use List,Stack, Queue or Map

Comment: Like a `List<Shoe>` for which you need a `Shoe` class

Comment: I think that you must to use List, Stack, Queue or Map to store the information. But the way you code and decode the information it's a your choice. You need to create a Shoes class or, if you like you have to import javatuples, a thirdy part library and work with it.

Comment: In the worst case you could use a Object[] of size 4, but that's just a dirty way to create an object without declaring a class

Comment: Please turn to your instructor. The only *meaningful* way to solve this is to **first** create one or more classes that model the *items* your code has to deal with. Like a Shoe class, that has various different properties. Then you can write equals() and hashCode() methods for that class that make sense. And then you might use other collection classes, such as `List<Shoe>`, or maybe `Map<Shoe, Double>` (in case the price would not be a fixed property of each shoe), and so on. Clarify that first.

Comment: Seriously: OO programming is about enclosing attributes that belong together. Having multiple "flat" lists for each attribute, and "connecting" them via a specific index: bad idea!

Comment: U can look at `Pair<K,V>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a map, each key has be unique. You cannot use the sizes as a key since there are not unique.

From your problem description:

> I have a lot of pairs of shoes, and every shoe has a size, a colour
>   and a price. The pairs of shoes must be **ordered** by their size.

a map doesn't seem to be a good choice since Maps are *generally* no ordered (except for `SortedMap`). You want a data structure that could be ordered according to a specific criteria. A `List` seems like a really good choice. The most common implementation of list is `ArrayList`.

You first need a class to store your shoes object that should look like this:

```
public class Shoe{
    int size;
    Color color; // Color is an enum, but it can be a String if you want to be less restrictive
    int price;

    public Shoe(int size, Color color, int price) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can store your shoes in your list that way:

```
List<Shoe> shoes = new ArrayList<>();
shoes.add(new Shoe(36, Color.BLACK, 30));
shoes.add(new Shoe(36, Color.WHITE, 35));
shoes.add(new Shoe(37, Color.BLACK, 40));
shoes.add(new Shoe(38, Color.BLACK, 40));
...
```

And once your list is filled, you can order them by size:

```
shoes.sort(Comparator.comparing(Shoe::getSize));
```

---

Alternative : you can create a `TreeMap<Integer,List<Shoe>>` (a sorted map that maps keys to a list to resolve key collisions) using the same comparator, that way even if you insert new shoes, it stays ordered, but it looks outside of the level of your problem.

Comment: I'm also allowed to use SortedMap, sorry for not specifying this from the start, I am beginner in programming and I was told that I must use List,Stack, Queue, Map, SortedMap, PriorityQueue, etc. (one of these). Your answer is very helpful and might be the right one for my problem. Now I'm learning how to use Map and List  and I haven't any knowledge about TreeMap and it's a little difficult to understand now exactly how it's working.

Comment: Since you're a beginner in programming, I really don't think your teacher wants you to come with the SortedMap answer, the List answer seems to be the most obvious one. (By the way a SortedMap is a Map so no need to specify it)

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 maps for this purposes. First map will contain name of shoes as a key, and map as value. Second map - properties. Something like:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> shoes = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> shoeProps = new HashMap<>();
shoeProps.put("color", "red");
shoeProps.put("size", 38);
shoeProps.put("price", 35);
shoes.put("nike", shoeProps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step One: understand the data.

You do not have one map of data,
you have a hierarchy of maps for your data.

Top map: maps the shoe size to a map of "details"

Details map: maps color to price

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Map to store and the key may same，try use google guava [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava)